# Running python-shell from ElectronJS script

Tags: python, node.js, electron

I'm creating a simple desktop app with Electron JS and Python. I tried a tutorial which indicates that it's more simple to communicate with Python back end with python-shell module. I cannot run the app without error related to that module.

Firstly I started with following code:

```
var pyshell =  require('python-shell');

pyshell.run('hello.py',  function  (err, results)  {
 if  (err)  throw err;
 console.log('hello.py finished.');
 console.log('results', results);
});
```

However it resulted in error saying that "**pyshell.run is not a function**". So I tried replacing first line with `let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')`. Also, tried `const` instead of `let`. It doesn't work, and pop ups error message **"Uncaught Exception: Error: spawn py ENOENT**". None of examples provided by Internet works for me... Where is the problem?

Comment: python should be in path, type python in a command prompt check it is working, if it is not working then setup environment variables

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can assign a const like ;

```
const pyshell = require('python-shell').PythonShell
// or
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell')
```

and your code does not work without options because command needs a directory, you should use python-shell like;

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');


var options = {
    scriptPath : path.join(__dirname, '/YOUR PYTHON DIRECTORY'),
    args : [],
    //mode: "json"
};

let pyshell = new PythonShell('test.py', options);

pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log(message);
    console.log(typeof message);
});
```